# UploadProgressChanged event not being called properly

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient, asyncfileupload

With the following code:

```
using (var uploadClient = new WebClient()) {
    uploadClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(util.ftp_user, util.ftp_pass);
    uploadClient.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
    uploadClient.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadProgressCompleted);
    uploadClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(util.URIstr + picName), "POST", filenamewAdress);
    }
```

```
public void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("UploadProgressCalledback");
}
```

```
public void UploadProgressCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Completed");
}
```

The **UploadProgressChangedEventHandler** is not being called, but **UploadFileCompletedEventHandler** is being called and the file is being uploaded correctly.
What am I missing?

Comment: The old `WebClient` is deprecated. You should use the new [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Also consider to use the async API instead of the event based: use `await UploadFileTaskAsync()` instead. But as already mentioned, switch to the HttpClient.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
uploadClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(util.URIstr + picName), "POST", filenamewAdress);
```

To

```
uploadClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(util.URIstr + picName), "STOR", filenamewAdress);
```